# How do i get user profile in django 1.7

Tags: python, django

I want to fetch each and every detail of user profile. I know function    `get_profile()` has been depreciated.

I want get user profile and then pass it as context to template.

Actually I am making a "Edit user profile" functionality.

My Model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

And views:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    profile = request.user.userprofile

    context_dict = {'profile': profile}

    return render_to_response('appname/dashboard.html', context_dict, context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit both `User` and `Profile` instance you have to use two forms:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        class = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        class = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user', )

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = user.userprofile
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if all([user_form.is_valid(), profile_form.is_valid()]):
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('.')
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html',
                       {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

And the template should contain both forms in the single `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
    <button>Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Now i am using "profile = request.user.userprofile" but still i am unable to get other fields from auth_user table. Eg: first_name etc

Comment: Yes the above is correct but how does i get user's first_name or last_name?

Comment: You should use two form classes. See the updated answer.  And, BTW, I suggest you to use `render()` instead of `render_to_template`.

Comment: You can exclude the `username` field from `UserForm.Meta.fields` tuple so only `first_name` and `last_name` fields will be shown in the form.